# How to Initialize the Task Object?

Tags: c#, .net, styles, code-readability

This question is trivial and it is for readability. I would just like to know weather the following line of code has any alternative ? Is that code is correct in the means of Readability and style?

```
Task newTask = new Task(() => { });
```

EDIT:

This task will be created when certain condition/rule met. In that case i would assign an `Action` to this class.

```
if(condition Met && newTask.Status != TaskStatus.Running )
{
  newTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(Action);
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: So your question is:  "Is this the idiomatic way to express a no-op task in C#?"

Comment: yes. i would like to initialize when it is required and not running

Comment: So what is your question now?

Comment: I would like to know whether this code convention to create  a task is correct?

Comment: If you are concerned with readability and style, then I'd suggest `var newTask = new Task(() => { });`, ie don't repeat `Task` when it's not required.

Answer (score 1):

A Task object is not mean to be run multiple times and started and stopped at will.  If you cancel a task or it runs to completion you are meant to create a new Task object the next time you want to execute it again.  You can keep a reference to your task object and cancel it using a `CancellationTokenSource`.

I would suggest simply keeping track of whether the task is running by either a bool variable or a Task variable itself where a null value indicates the task isn't running.  For example:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
private Task _task;

public void StartDoingSomething()
{
    if (_task == null)
    {
        _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Worker, _tokenSource.Token)
                            .ContinueWith(_ => _task = null);
    }
}

public void StopDoingSomething()
{
    if (_task != null)
    {
        _tokenSource.Cancel();
    }
}

private void Worker()
{
    while (!_tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // Do some unit of work
    }
}
```